# npm install - Failed at the node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall script

Tags: node.js, node-modules, npm-install

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR**! Failed at the node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall script.**
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

P:S - my node version is v12.18.3 and npm verion is 6.14.3

I have tried all solutions like :

1. deleted package-lock.json
2. deleted node-module
3. run npm install gulp-sass
4. run npm install node -sass@latest

But still issue persist .
Please help me out .

Comment: Have you tried `npm rebuild node-sass`?

Comment: Yes, it did not work :(

Comment: That error message is not helpful, it's just the generic message npm prints out for any error. Look further up the log output to find hints what actually went wrong